# Placeholder in my input shifts up and down when the input type is toggled from password to text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I have the styles below on a standard input element in react. The input has a button to toggle the type from text to password. The issue is the placeholder moves up and down about 2px when viewed on Chrome, but no issues on Safari. How can I fix this?

I added the 1px of padding-bottom the the password type which seems to fix it in Chrome but it will mess it up in Safari. Any idea what's causing my placeholder to shift?

```css
    .input {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif, -apple-system, system-ui;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 20px;
      background-color: inherit;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      letter-spacing: 0.5px;
      &::placeholder,
      &[type='password']::placeholder {
        font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif, -apple-system, system-ui;
        font-size: 14px;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
        line-height: 20px;
      }
      &[type='password'] {
        font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 2.5px;
        line-height: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 1px;
      }
      &:focus {
        outline: none;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Add your input code to the question

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by reducing the font size of the password text.